# Evento dispara uma vez a mais para cada clique

Tags: jquery

Estava a fazer uma aplicação de uma loja, na aplicação, quando clicado na imagem do produto, abre um modal indicando a quantidade. Este modal possui um botão `submit` para enviar os dados na base de dados.

Ao clicar no `submit` a primeira vez o evento corre sem problemas. 
O problema é que na segunda vez que se clica acontece como se eu clicasse 2 vezes, na terceira como se clicasse 3 vezes, e assim por diante.

Procurei e achei uma solução: `unbind()` ou `.off()`, mas não entendi o porque de acontecer, sendo que quando acaba um evento `click` deveria acabar, não?

**Em suma, as minhas dúvidas são estas:**

No final do evento *click* a função continua a ser executada?

Se o `.unbind()` desativa todos os eventos `click` ou outros, o `bind` serve para ativá-los? Ou seja faz o mesmo que o `.trigger()`?

Percebi que existe uma diferença entre:

`$(document).on('click', "#div", function(){....});` e `$("#div").click(function(){...});`

Só não percebi qual, mas parece que ao usar a segunda opção, existirá muitas vezes algum erro, por isso é sempre melhor usar a primeira opção, correto?

**EDITADO**

Como pedido irei adicionar o código:

```
<!-- TRIGGER --> 
<button class="botaopreco" onclick="addcart(<? echo $prod['id']; ?>)">
    Adicionar 
    <i class="fa fa-cart-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

Modal

```
<!--:::::::::: MODAL :::::::: -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal<? echo $contador; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">DETALHES</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="imagem-modal">
                <img src="imagens/<?echo $prod['caminho_imagem']; ?>">
            </div>


            <div class="modal-info">

                <div class="info-title">
                 DETALHES
                </div>


                <div class="info-info">
                    <? echo $prod['detalhes']; ?>
                </div>

            </div>

            <br><br>

            <div class="modal-info">

                <div class="info-title-two">
                STOCK
                </div>

                <div class="info-info-two">
                <?
                    if($prod['stock'] == "EM STOCK")
                {
                    echo '<span id="stock'.$prod['id'].'">'.$prod['stock'].'</span>';
                    echo '<i style="color:#7CBB00;position:relative;left:50%;" class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>'; 
                }

if($prod['stock'] == "ESGOTADO")
{
   echo '<span id="stock'.$prod['id'].'">'.$prod['stock'].'</span>';
   echo '<i style="color:#EA4335;position:relative;left:50%;" class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>'; 
}
if($prod['stock'] == "APENAS POR ENCOMENDA")
{
    echo '<span id="stock'.$prod['id'].'">'.$prod['stock'].'</span>';
    echo '<i style="color:#FBBC05;position:relative;left:50%;" class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>'; 
}
?>
</div>

    <div class="info-title-two" style="margin-left:5%;">
        PREÇO
    </div>

    <div class="info-info-two">
        <? echo floatval($prod['preco']); ?>€
    </div>


    <br><br>

    <div class="info-title-two">
    MARCA
    </div>

    <div class="info-info-two">
     <?
        echo $prod['marca'];
     ?>
    </div>

    <div class="info-title-two" style="margin-left:5%;">
        DIMENSÕES
    </div>

    <div class="info-info-two">
        <? echo $prod['dimensoes']; ?>
    </div>

    </div>
```

Jquery

```
    function addcart(x)
    {
        //FECHAR MODAL
        $("#modal-overlay"+x).click(function(){
            $("#modal-overlay"+x).hide();
            $("#modal-in"+x).hide();
        });

        var stock = $("#stock"+x).text();

        //VERIFICAR SE EXISTE STOCK
        if(stock == "EM STOCK" || stock == "APENAS POR ENCOMENDA")
        {
            $("#modal-in"+x).show();
            $("#modal-overlay"+x).show();

            //ADICIONAR NO CARRINHO
            $("#quant-enter"+x).off().on('click',function() {

                var prod = x;
                var quant = 0;
                var quant = $("#quant-val"+x).val();

                $.post('adicionar_item.php',
                {
                    prod:prod,
                    quant:quant
                },
                function(data)
                {
                    if(data == "404")
                    {
                        location.href = 'login.php';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $("#modal-in"+x).hide();
                        $("#modal-overlay"+x).hide();
                        $(".hue").text(data);
                        swal({   
                            title: "Adicionado!",   
                            text: "O produto foi adicionado ao seu carrinho", 
                            timer: 2000,  
                            imageUrl: "imagens/shop.png" 
                        });
                    }
                });
            });

        }
        else
        {
            swal("Erro!","O item escolhido não se encontra em stock","error");
        }
    }
```

P.S. Para criar id's únicos eu crio um estático e adiciono a chave primária da tabela da base de dados, depois passo pela função.

Comment: Sem ver o seu código original, não é possível dizer qual era o problema. Mas provavelmente a cada clique você estava acrescentando mais um event listener sem perceber.

Comment: Coloca o código aqui.

Comment: Então, acho se está clicado é caindo soma, use declaração para zerar contagem. Isso esta difícil sem código e posso ajudar =.=

Comment: Essas situações, geralmente, aconteciam quando eu carregava páginas que continham javascripts diversas vezes. O melhor é utilizar o evento __.on__ e evitar o uso dos eventos inline html. Em resumo uma diferença entre `jQuery("#div")` e `jQuery(document).on(..,"#div")` é: o primeiro vai dar o **bind** nos elementos que já existirem na tela e se algum  for adicionado dinamicamente o evento (neste elemento) não será executado. O segundo já _"engloba"_ esses elementos criados dinamicamente.